# пагинация php не работает помогите

Tags: php, пагинация

в **index.php** код собирает шаблон

```
<?php
require 'config/config.php';
require DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/templates/header.tpl';
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
$page = array_key_exists('page', $_GET) ? $_GET["page"] : null;
}
else{
$page = 'index';
}
$path = "pages/$page.php";
 if (file_exists($path)) {
       include $path;
    }
    else {
        require DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/pages/404.php'
}
require DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/templates/footer.tpl';
?>
```

По этому коду страница открываются по ссылки

1. `http://test.ru/?page=about_us`
   Если нет такой страницы то грузит шаблон 404
2. `http://test.ru/?page=about_usап`

Вопрос? )))
Как разрешит загрузку страницы пагинации если его нету в папке pages

1. `http://test.ru/?page=reviews?id=1`
   Получаеться **`reviews?id=1`** это пагинация этой страницы нету в папке pages и выводит ошибку 404

Comment: знак вопроса в запрос используется единожды и отделяет путь от параметров. сами параметры между собой отделяются амперсандом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо поправить url. `http://test.ru/?page=reviews?id=1` -> `http://test.ru/?page=reviews&id=1`.